# Is there anything like Objective-C Categories in Java?

Tags: java, objective-c-category

In Objective C land you can make `Category` classes where you can kind of 'extend' the functionality of Apple Core Classes. For example the `UIColor` class has a myriad of colors but let's say you want a specific theme for your project, you can simply create a `Category` for it like so:

```
@interface UIColor (CustomColors) 

+ (UIColor) myCustomColor;

@end

@implementation UIColor (CustomColors) 

+ (UIColor) myCustomColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:...];
}

@end
```

Is there anything similar to this in Java?

Comment: Alas no, not in Java.  But check out Scala which runs on the JVM too as it does have a feature which can implicitly wrap classes with extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

In Android (and Java in general), you have to use subclassing to achieve the same results.

E.g.:

```
public class MyView extends View {
    public void someCustomMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean you can do that in Objective C as well. 

`@interface MyView : View

- (void)someCustomMethod;

@end`

//... etc.

I was wondering specifically about categories.

Comment: Well, whereas you can choose between  category and subclass in Objective-C, your only option in Java is the subclass. (which is not a big deal in my opinion)

Comment: Gotcha :( Java why u do this

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 added default imple's for interfaces, but the idea of a category (iOS) or an extension (Swift) doesn't exist yet in Android.